# Default document is not loading- Not getting processed

Tags: iis-7, default-document

We have set default document for one website.

When we hit IP:port we receive blank page.

But if we hit IP:port/Defaultdoc.html it is loading.

It seems IIS is not processing the default page.

What could be causing this issue. Is it related to some IIS modules.

When we hit site we are getting 200 OK but no processing.

Comment: Is `Defaultdoc.html` the first doc in the list of default docs for the website ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the default document was disabled at IIS level. Hence the sites were loading default document.

We have enabled this and resolved the issue.